# Do these Windows executable meta data traits mean what I think they do?

Tags: x86-64, disassembly, portable-executable

I'm learning Assembly as part of a malware analysis project and trying to use a few Node.js libraries to scrape executables from GitHub and disassemble them.

Specifically I'm focusing on x86-64 PE.

But a disassembler, such as [the one I chose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iced-x86#move-code-in-memory-eg-hook-a-function) isn't necessarily supposed to find the instructions in a particular executable format such as in a PE.

In addition to first needing to know where my instructions should start, when I started using the disassembler, I realized I also needed to set a particular RIP value for the program to start at. I don't fully understand why some programs start at different memory offsets, but supposedly it's to allow other cooperating processes to put memory in the same block. Or something like that.

So my goal is to know:

- the correct starting value for the RIP
- the correct byte to look for the first instruction, beyond the header.

So I used [a library](https://github.com/Anadian/executable-metadata/blob/HEAD/API.md) to find meta data, like so:

```
let metaData = await executableMetadata.getMetadataObjectFromExecutableFilePath_Async(execPath);
```

Which when passed an exe with a header like this:

```
0:      4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00
16:     b8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
32:     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
48:     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00
64:     0e 1f ba 0e 00 b4 09 cd 21 b8 01 4c cd 21 54 68
80:     69 73 20 70 72 6f 67 72 61 6d 20 63 61 6e 6e 6f
96:     74 20 62 65 20 72 75 6e 20 69 6e 20 44 4f 53 20
112:    6d 6f 64 65 2e 0d 0d 0a 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
128:    50 45 00 00 4c 01 03 00 91 3f 9a ef 00 00 00 00
144:    00 00 00 00 e0 00 22 00 0b 01 30 00 00 12 00 00
```

tells us:

```
{
  format: 'PE',
  pe_header_offset_16le: 128,
  machine_type: 332,
  machine_type_object: {
    constant: 'IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386',
    description: 'Intel 386 or later processors and compatible processors'
  },
  number_of_sections: 3,
  timestamp: -275103855,
  coff_symbol_table_offset: 0,
  coff_number_of_symbol_table_entries: 0,
  size_of_optional_header: 224,
  characteristics_bitflag: 34,
  characteristics_bitflags: [
    {
      constant: 'IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE',
      description: 'Image only. This indicates that the image file is valid and can be run. If this flag is not set, it indicates a linker error.',
      flag_code: 2
    },
    {
      constant: 'IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE',
      description: 'Application can handle > 2-GB addresses.',
      flag_code: 32
    }
  ],
  object_type_code: 267,
  object_type: 'PE32',
  linker: { major_version: 48, minor_version: 0 },
  size_of_code: 4608,
  size_of_initialized_data: 2048,
  size_of_uninitialized_data: 0,
  address_of_entry_point: 12586,
  base_of_code: 8192,
  windows_specific: {
    image_base: 4194304,
    section_alignment: 8192,
    file_alignment: 512,
    major_os_version: 4,
    minor_os_version: 0,
    major_image_version: 0,
    minor_image_version: 0,
    major_subsystem_version: 6,
    minor_subsystem_version: 0,
    win32_version: 0,
    size_of_image: 32768,
    size_of_headers: 512,
    checksum: 0,
    subsystem: {
      constant: 'IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_CUI',
      description: 'The Windows character subsystem',
      subsystem_code: 3
    },
    dll_characteristics: 34144,
    dll_characteristic_flags: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  base_of_data: 16384
}
```

And from this, I think maybe I found the two pieces of info I needed:

- First instruction byte: `windows_specific.size_of_headers` (512)
- RIP starting value: `address_of_entry_point` (12586)

But I'm basically guessing. Could anyone more familiar with this meta data explain the correct properties to look at to get the info I need?

Comment: If your want to go further with the malware analysis I advise you to take the time to learn the PE(32+) format. You can find the address of the entry point in the NT header of the PE. That's your RIP value and first instruction. Note that setting RIP in iced-x86 is mostly for aesthetic purposes. Also, Knowing how Windows handle processes (i.e. the PEB, TEB, the loading of DLL), how an OS generally works (i.e. virtual memory, the kernel), how to program in Windows (i.e. Win32 API) and how the x86 protection and architecture work is also strongly advised but not strictly needed right now.

Comment: Also, beware that PE has TLS callbacks that run before the entry point and you may need to process the relocation and import directories before disassembling the code (once you have a working prototype). Finally, while I don't particularly like it, most libraries/tools in the infosec community are coded in python (in case you wanted something ready).

Comment: @MargaretBloom Lol yeah I noticed the python in the agency I work at. I don't like it either. Thanks for the advice. I'll take a hard look at the inner workings of the header. I was hoping I could sort of skip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows executable file begins with 16bit DOS stub. Double word at the file offset 60 contains offset of DWORD PE signature, in your example it is `60: 80 00 00 00`, i.e. 128 in decimal.
PE signature is immediately followed with *COFF file header* (file offset 132).
You may want to confront your hexadecimal dump with structure of headers in assembly language. [COFF_FILE_HEADER.Machine](https://euroassembler.eu/easource/pfcoff.htm#PFCOFF_FILE_HEADER) is `132: 4C 01`, i.e. `0x14C` which signalizes 32bit executable. In 64bit executable it would be `0x8664`.

File header is followed by *COFF section headers*. You are interrested in those sections, which have set bit `SCN_MEM_EXECUTE=0x2000_0000` in [COFF_SECTION_HEADER.Characteristics](https://euroassembler.eu/easource/pfcoff.htm#PFCOFF_SECTION_HEADER).

[COFF_SECTION_HEADER.PointerToRawData](https://euroassembler.eu/easource/pfcoff.htm#PFCOFF_SECTION_HEADER) specifies file offset of the start of code.
Dissect out `.SizeOfRawData` bytes which start at this file offset and submit that portion of code it to your disassembler.
Beware that on run-time the code will be in fact mapped to `.VirtualAddress`, different from `.PointerToRawData`.